# Render output of multiple expressions in one ERB block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, helper

I have a helper that looks like this:

```
if current_user.find_voted_items(vote_scope: :inspired).include?(post)
   link_to vote_inspired_post_path(post, vote_scope: :inspired), method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure this post Inspires you?' }, class: "btn btn-default" do
    "<i class='fa fa-lightbulb-o'></i> <br />Inspired".html_safe
   end
   link_to vote_happy_post_path(post, vote_scope: :happy), method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure this post makes you happy?' }, class: "btn btn-success" do
    "<i class='fa fa-smile-o'></i> <br />Happy".html_safe
   end
   link_to vote_disappointed_post_path(post, vote_scope: :disappointed), method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure this post disappointed you?' }, class: "btn btn-info" do
    "<i class='fa fa-meh-o'></i> <br />Disappointed".html_safe
   end
   link_to vote_upset_post_path(post, vote_scope: :upset), method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure this post upsets you?' }, class: "btn btn-inverse" do
    "<i class='fa fa-frown-o'></i> <br />Upset".html_safe
   end
end
```

I need all the links and their nested `<i>` tags to be rendered - but for some reason, this version is just rendering the last line.

All of that is inside a method called `show_vote_buttons(post)`, that is being called like this in the view: `<%= show_vote_buttons(@post) %>`

What's the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the reason behind this is that `<%= %>` renders the output of `show_vote_buttons` method. This method doesn't explicitly return anything, so the last evaluated expression is returned, in your case, the last `link_to` output.

In a general case, if you have not used a helper method and just pasted it's body instead with multiple `link_to` calls, you would get the same behavior. The reason is similar: `<%= %>` does not  render each `link_to`, it executes code inside `<%= %>` and then outputs the result of last evaluated expression.

I see two different approaches to change the output:

1. **Helper method**: concatenate the output of all evaluated expressions and print as one string:
   1.1 using `<<`  and parenthesis `()` around each `link_to`;
   1.2 creating a string with double quotes `"` and interpolating each `link_to` output with `#{}` in it;
   1.3 using [`concat`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat);
2. **Partial views**: build a separate view from your existing helper method and use `<%= %>` to output each `link_to`.

*P.S. After testing all four methods I've come to a conclusion (here comes a personal opinion) that the second method is more preferable, at least because it keeps rendering in the views and avoids concatenation that can look messy. Similar approach is used, for example, in the Devise gem, where all shared links are located in the `app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb`* partial.

Comment: I would love to see the representation indeed. I kinda get what you are saying, it feels a bit confusing though. Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do, other than in a helper? I am trying to not clutter my views.

Comment: Interesting, so I would have a partial for each state - i.e. a partial for `inspired`, `happy`, `disappointed`, `upset`, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

> but for some reason, this version is just rendering the last line.

That reason is because in Ruby, if a method doesn't have an explicit `return`, then the returned value of a method is the value of the last line that got executed before a method exited. If you want to return multiple values from a method, use the `return` keyword and comma-separate your values.

```
#will return an array [1,2,3]
def some_method
 return 1,2,3
end
```

Also, I do agree with the other answers that your code should be more DRY, but I was simply trying to clarify your original question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is perfectly explained by @suslov around this answer. Metaprogramming might keep code DRY:

```
DATA = {
  inspired: { ico: 'fa-lightbulb-o', 
              msg: 'Are you sure this post Inspires you?',
              btn: 'btn-default' },
  happy: {    ico: 'fa-smile-o', 
              msg: 'Are you sure this post makes you happy?',
              btn: 'btn-success' },
  ... }

if current_user.find_voted_items(vote_scope: :inspired).include?(post)
  DATA.map do |k, v|
   instance_eval %Q{
     link_to vote_#{k}_post_path(post, vote_scope: :#{k}), 
               method: :post, 
               data: { confirm: #{v[:msg]} }, 
               class: "btn #{v[:btn]}" do
       "<i class='fa #{v[:ico]'></i> <br />#{k.capitalize}".html_safe
     end
   }.join($/) # return them all, concatenated with separator
  end
end
```

Comment: I agree about the code being much more DRY, but first I have to get it to work. That being said, this solution seems waaaaay too complicated and more confusing. I appreciate the effort though.

Comment: To me it seems waaaaay easier to read, handle and support, because of everything is actually handled by the static `DATA` constant, but it it’s too complicated for you, it’s your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with this code

```
if current_user.find_voted_items(vote_scope: :inspired).include?(post)
concat(link_to vote_inspired_post_path(post, vote_scope: :inspired), method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure this post Inspires you?' }, class: "btn btn-default" do
  safe_concat(content_tag(:i, "Inspired", calss: "fa fa-lightbulb-o"))
end)
concat(link_to vote_happy_post_path(post, vote_scope: :happy), method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure this post makes you happy?' }, class: "btn btn-success" do
  safe_concat(content_tag(:i, "Happy", calss: "fa fa-smile-o"))
end)
concat(link_to vote_disappointed_post_path(post, vote_scope: :disappointed), method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure this post disappointed you?' }, class: "btn btn-info" do
  safe_concat(content_tag(:i, "Disappointed", calss: "fa fa-meh-o"))
end)
concat(link_to vote_upset_post_path(post, vote_scope: :upset), method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure this post upsets you?' }, class: "btn btn-inverse" do
  safe_concat(content_tag(:i, "Upset", calss: "fa fa-frown-o"))
end)
end
```

***Note:*** Didn't tested it.